# How to add a Bookmark within excel using VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, bookmarks

I am trying to reduce some manual work through **vbscript**.

I have to create a summary page with has the list of all details with hyperlinks (bookmark).  Once the link is clicked it has to take me to the sheet which has the details.

I tried to create a hyperlink like this.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "=HYPERLINK("Sheet2!A1", "Inventory")"
```

but it didn't work out. The above code works for website link though.

```
 objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com"", ""Google"")"
```

I'm stuck here. Please help me how to create a bookmark using VBSCRIPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. :)

The below code would work fine if we add a **#** to **Address** i.e #Sheet2!A1.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A1", "Inventory")"
```

We should ensure that double quotes are also available while pasting in the cell.  The hyperlink value should be like the below

```
"=HYPERLINK("&Chr(34)&"#Sheet2!A1"&Chr(34)&","&Chr(34)&"Link"&Chr(34)&")"
```

where **Chr(34)** is double quotes.